# Nested form yields parameters with extra level between parent and child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm building a user and then a plan for that user in one form. I'd expect the parameters to look something like this:

```
"user"=> {
    "email" => "",
    "plans_attributes", => {
       "invite_code" => "",
       "zipcode => ""
    }
}
```

But instead it looks like this:

```
"user"=> {
   "email"=>"", 
   "plans_attributes"=> {
      "0" => {
         "invite_code"=>"", 
         "zipcode"=>""
      }
   }
}
```

Not sure why the 0 shows up... is that normal?? If not, how do I get rid of it? If so, how do I get the parameters to accept appropriately?

**Code:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :plans #a user definitely can have more than one plan, but at the time of sign_up, they can only create one plan
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :plans
end

class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

    <% resource.plans.build %>
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
        <%= devise_error_messages! %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :email %>

          <!-- Begin nested form for plan -->
          <%= f.fields_for :plans do |p| %>
            <%= p.hidden_field :invite_code %>
            <%= p.hidden_field :zipcode %>
          <%= end %>
    <% end %>
```

Note, if the 0 is supposed to be there, not sure how to get this working:

```
def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
    u.permit( 
      :email,
      plans_attributes: [
        0: [
          :invite_code, 
          :zipcode,
        ] 
      ]  
    )
  end
end

#Throws an unexpected ':' after 0 error even if 0 is a string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero is expected. If you have more than one `plans_attributes` it would show up as:
`{ 0 => {"invite_code"=>"", "zipcode"=>""}
1 => {"invite_code"=>"", "zipcode=>""}}`  etc.

That way, you could update all of the user's plans at the same time.

Best I can tell based on what you've written, your devise_parameter_sanitizer should look like this:
`def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
    u.permit(:email, plans: [:invite_code, :zipcode])
  end
end`

Hope that helps.